# получить список популярных запросов гугл/яндекс

Tags: seo

здравствуйте, можно ли как то получить список популярных запросов, допустим по игровым/кино/компьютерным или др. тематикам в поисковиках? Причем именно на текущий момент, или можно сказать в реальном времени, а не статью собранных популярных запросов за прошлый или позапрошлый год

Comment: Клик https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно посмотреть статистику популярных запросов [Google](https://trends.google.com/trends/)

А тут [Яндекс](https://wordstat.yandex.com/)